# Convert number to number between 0 to 2

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I am trying to create an arc using `javascript` with the total count of four items. For that I need to calculate percentage of total count of each item and assign to the variables `perc1,perc2,perc3,perc4`. But it's total should not go beyond `2`. I have generated sample arc using the dummy percentage given below.

I would get total values from database instead which should be converted and used.
For ex: if I have values like 129, 53, 111, 95. How can I get calculated percentage for the variables `perc1,perc2,perc3,perc4`?

```
var totalPercent = .75;
var padRad = 0.025;
var percToRad = function (perc) {
    return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
};
var degToRad = function (deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
};
var percToDeg = function (perc) {
    return perc * 360;
};


//****Set up the arc generator*****
perc1 = 0.6;
perc2 = 0.4;
perc3 = 0.4;
perc4 = 0.6;
var next_start = totalPercent;

arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc1 / 4);
next_start += perc1 / 4;
const arc1 = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius).startAngle(arcStartRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc2 / 4);
next_start += perc2 / 4;
const arc2 = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius).startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc3 / 4);
next_start += perc3 / 4;
const arc3 = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius).startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc4 / 4);
const arc4 = d3.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius).startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);
```

Comment: you sum the 4 values -> TOTAL. You take percentage of each value from this total. you have the percent, now total is 2... you take the percent previously calculated from 2

Comment: you sum the 4 values -> TOTAL. You take percentage of each value from this total. you have the percent, now total is 2... you take the percent previously calculated from 2. To take your example: 129 + 53 + 111 + 95 = 388. 129/388=0.332474226804124. So 129 is 33,2474%. Apply this percentage to 2... and so on